# Access: ConcatRelated works on a table, but not on a query

Tags: function, vba, ms-access, concatenation

I have been using [Allen Browne's ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function, and while it works fine when the data comes from a table, but it doesn't work when the data comes from a query.

The green 'running query' bar appears for a few seconds, but then when it tries to display the data it shows only one field from the first row, runs very slowly and can take a few minutes to display the first screen of records. I've not managed to leave it long enough to complete the result set, have to shut down Access using the task manager.

Is the query getting run each time the function is called? That could explain why it takes so long but seems unlikely.

Is this a problem with the function, with the query that is calling the function, or the query that the source data is coming from?

Comment: Just a guess, but it may have to do with indexing, or lack thereof in your query.

Comment: Will have a look at this - it is fairly slow, and it uses First() to get a number of fields from 5 unioned queries which are based on five tables and are each linked to another multi-level query, so there may be scope to speed this up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using that function in the Immediate window.

```
CompanyID = 7
? ConcatRelated("OrderDate", "tblOrders", "CompanyID = " & CompanyID)
12/11/2012, 12/12/2012, 12/13/2012
```

The function ...

1. creates this SQL statement

   SELECT OrderDate FROM tblOrders WHERE CompanyID  = 7
2. opens a `Recordset` based on that statement
3. loops through the `Recordset` adding each `OrderDate` value to its output string

IOW, `ConcatRelated()` performs quite a bit of work each time you call it.  And when you call it as a field expression in a query, it has to perform all that work again for each row of the query's result set.

In addition to that "fixed overhead", `ConcatRelated()` may lead to an additional performance cost:  Without an index on `CompanyID`, the db engine would have to use a full table scan of `tblOrders` to find the rows which satisfy the `WHERE` clause.

Your question asks about the impact of using a query instead of a table with `ConcatRelated()`.  Then the function's internal SQL statement will be:

```
SELECT OrderDate FROM YourQuery WHERE CompanyID  = 7
```

In addition to the performance challenges imposed by `ConCatRelated()` with a table, you risk 2 more which may dramatically increase the workload.

1. If `YourQuery` demands a lot of effort by the db engine, it must put in that effort to create each row of the parent query's result set.
2. You increase the likelihood that the db engine will not be able to used an index for the `WHERE` clause in the function's internal SQL statement.  Even if there is an index on `CompanyID` in the underlying table source of `YourQuery`, the db engine may not see enough benefit from using it.

So while `ConCatRelated()` is useful, using it is costly.  That's not because of any design error in the function.  Rather the nature of the task is just so expensive regardless of what approach you use to accomplish it.  And asking that function to use a query instead of a table likely inflates the cost.

Comment: Okay, instead of using the table, I put it in a simple select query and the function could cope with that. So the problem isn't in any use of the query itself. ~ The query that I need to use can take up to 4 seconds to return all results, which is a lot in comparison to some other queries, so is it likely the nature of this query that is slowing things down @HansUp? ~ I can try to optimise it, or possibly find a way to get that data into a table beforehand, but that will probably involve the world of VBA....

Comment: Yes, I think you've nailed it: you have a slow query as the *strTable* option for `ConCatRelated()`.  If you can load a scratch table to give to `ConCatRelated()`, that could speed up the function.  But then you have to deal with loading the scratch table.  There isn't a cheap/easy Access solution to do what you want from `ConCatRelated()`.