# Can I use a query to convert row data to a csv field

Tags: ms-access

I have this data table:

> ```
> | Color | Fruit      |
> |-------|------------|
> | Blue  | Blueberry  |
> | Green | Grape      |
> | Green | Lime       |
> | Red   | Cherry     | 
> | Red   | Cherry     | 
> | Red   | Grape      | 
> | Red   | Strawberry |
> ```

And I want to create a query using that input to produce this:

> ```
> | Color | A CSV List Of Fruits that color |
> |-------|---------------------------------| 
> | Blue  | Blueberry                       | 
> | Green | Grape,Lime                      |              
> | Red   | Cherry,Grape,Strawberry         |
> ```

In the source data some fruits (grapes in this example) appear in multiple colors, and some fruits (cherries in this example) appear multiple times under the same color.  The result must include the grapes as shown, and only list the cherries once in the CSV result.

In the real data I've represented by this simplified example, I never know in advance the maximum count of fruits associated with a single color.  If it matters it is safe to presume it will always be less than 100.  It's actually nearly always less than 10.

My hope is that this can be done entirely with query, without the need for VBA code.

If anybody can get me pointed towards a solution, I'd be grateful!

Comment: No, this requires VBA. Does this answer your question? [Access: ConcatRelated works on a table, but not on a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862302/access-concatrelated-works-on-a-table-but-not-on-a-query)

Comment: Eliminate duplicate fruits by using a DISTINCT query as source for the function. I have seen versions of this code that allow providing a complete SQL statement instead of just WHERE criteria as function argument. Modify as you see fit.