# Combine cells in access separated by comma

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation

I am new to access and coding.
I have a sheet comprising of huge data. I want some specified data in Access by running a query or VBA. What I want is to combine the data based on a column and each data separated by a comma. I am pasting the example of the sheet below:

Input sheet

[image: 1]

Output data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WEQc.png)

I tried to use COMMON but with no luck. Please help.

Comment: Not only do you want to combine fields, but then you want to combine records. Combining fields is simple concatenation, combining records will require VBA (Google Allen Browne ConcatRelated). This would be simpler if data structure was normalized. What does "no luck" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? I expect COMMON is not recognized in Access. Question is too broad. Make code attempt and when you have something with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Since each column allows only one type of product, why aren't column names the product and data a True/False? Regardless, data is not normalized and this complicates data manipulation. A UNION query could rearrange data to normalized structure and that dataset can be source for further manipulation.

Comment: I tried using COMMON, it gave an error as not recognized. I understand it is complicating the data a lot. I was able to merge the data in excel using a VBA, but want to achieve the same in access. In excel I have to use individual product columns and vlookup to get the result but want a better method to archive the same. wherein I jus run the query to achieve it. I totally agree this is complicated data and needs some help.

Comment: Don't know if better. The referenced Allen Browne procedure (and others like it) can perform slowly with large dataset. Throwing a UNION query in the mix can make it worse. Regardless of data structure, VBA is the only way to get desired output.

Comment: I did try the Allen brown method, but was unsuccessful. I got the error as undefined function for Concatrelated. Might be the result I require is more complicated.

Comment: Did you put the function in a general module? Module cannot have same name as procedure. Yes, your requirement is more complicated. Code will have to be tailored. It is preferred that data be posted as a text table, not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Allen Browne ConcatRelated function (often referenced, start with [Access: ConcatRelated works on a table, but not on a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862302/access-concatrelated-works-on-a-table-but-not-on-a-query)) with non-normalized data structure:

```
SELECT Data.LocationID, 
"Paste: " & ConcatRelated("CustomerID","Data","LocationID=" & [LocationID] & " AND NOT Product1 IS NULL")
& "; " & "Chips: " & ConcatRelated("CustomerID","Data","LocationID=" & [LocationID] & " AND NOT Product2 IS NULL")
& "; " & "Oil: " & ConcatRelated("CustomerID","Data","LocationID=" & [LocationID] & " AND NOT Product3 IS NULL")
& "; " & "Pulses: " & ConcatRelated("CustomerID","Data","LocationID=" & [LocationID] & " AND NOT Product4 IS NULL")
& "; " & "Salt: " & ConcatRelated("CustomerID","Data","LocationID=" & [LocationID] & " AND NOT Product5 IS NULL")
& "; " & "Sugar: " & ConcatRelated("CustomerID","Data","LocationID=" & [LocationID] & " AND NOT Product6 IS NULL")
AS PS
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.LocationID;
```

Data structure can be normalized with UNION query.

```
SELECT LocationID, CustomerID, Product1 AS Product FROM Data WHERE NOT Product1 IS NULL
UNION SELECT LocationID, CustomerID, Product2 FROM Data WHERE NOT Product2 IS NULL
UNION SELECT LocationID, CustomerID, Product3 FROM Data WHERE NOT Product3 IS NULL
UNION SELECT LocationID, CustomerID, Product4 FROM Data WHERE NOT Product4 IS NULL
UNION SELECT LocationID, CustomerID, Product5 FROM Data WHERE NOT Product5 IS NULL
UNION SELECT LocationID, CustomerID, Product6 FROM Data WHERE NOT Product6 IS NULL;
```

Then producing desired output will involve two more queries, each calling ConcatRelated function.

Query1:

```
SELECT LocationID, Product & ": " & 
ConcatRelated("CustomerID","unionData","LocationID=" & [LocationID] & " AND Product='" & [Product] & "'")
AS PS
FROM unionData
GROUP BY LocationID, Product;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT LocationID, 
ConcatRelated("PS","Query1","LocationID=" & [LocationID], "", "; ")
AS ProductSold
FROM Query1
GROUP BY LocationID;
```

Advantages of normalized data is the last 2 queries don't have to be modified regardless of how many products are involved and ConcatRelated function is not referenced in query as often. With non-normalized data, if you add more product columns, query will have to be modified to call function again for each. Normalize table structure and UNION query can be eliminated.